# How to split a line into segments of equal length?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a given line represented as a 2-d numpy-array, i.e.: `line=([x_1, y_1], ..., [x_n, y_n])`
I want to split that line into **segments** whose length - measured by `np.linalg.norm(np.diff(line), axis=0), axis=1)` is equal. For example, lets say my line object consists out of 2000 points. I want to select all points that are **segment_length** apart and keep the endpoints.

What I've tried so far:

```
   # Get contour length of interpolated trace
    distance = np.cumsum(norm(np.diff(line, axis=0), axis=1))
    
    # Use mod. division to indicate whether a specific segment length has been passed
    distance = np.mod(distance, segment_length)
    distance = np.append([0], distance) # Correction due to np.diff
    
    # Set boolean mask to select equidistant points from the interpolated trace
    length_diffs = np.diff(distance, axis=0)
    
    passed_sl = length_diffs < 0
    
    if keep_endpoints:
        mask = np.append(passed_sl, [True])
        mask[0] = True 
        
    else: # do not include endpoints
        mask = np.append(passed_sl, [False])
        print(mask[450:500])

    line_equidistant = line[mask]
```

However, when I run that program, I don't get the right result, the segment lengths have an error of about 10%.

Comment: For an L-shaped input like [[0,0], [1, 0], [1, 1]], if we want to split it into three segments, what are they supposed to be?

Comment: For 'segment_length=0.5', we should get a points at [[0, 0], [0.5, 0], [1, 0], [1, 0.5], [1, 1]]. However, I have much more points than that.

Comment: Note you can skip the `np.append` step by using `prepend=line[0]` in `numpy.diff`

Comment: Does anyone have an idea? Still not arriving at the solution....